# Final Deployment of React Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to NodeJS and come from Java world, but in last 3 month I have done quite good development.
I use ExpressJS and ReactJSin my first project, Now during development we use 2 http server 1 for ExpressJS back-end application and another for ReactJS front-end application.

Now is this the way we have to deploy on production or we can combine it as 1 application and deploy on 1 http server listening on port 80.

regards

Answer (score 0):

**Deploy a production React app to Heroku**

***1. Create a React App***

```
npm create-react-app heroku-deploy-test
cd heroku-deploy-test
```

[image]

***2. Create an Express JS server to serve your production build***

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port);
```

***In your `package.json` file, change the start script to the following: start:

  `"node server.js"`***

***3. Deploy to Heroku***

*If you don’t already have a Heroku account, create one here: https://signup.heroku.com/*
In your command line, run the following: ***`heroku login`***

You will need to type in your heroku credentials to the terminal. Once you have successfully entered your heroku credentials, run the following in your terminal to ***create*** a new deployed app:

```
heroku create heroku-deploy-test
```

(Replace `heroku-deploy-test` with your own app name.)

***Then push your app build to heroku with the following git in your terminal:***

```
git init 
git add . 
git commit -m "initial commit"
heroku git:remote -a heroku-deploy-test
git push heroku master
```

These commands install your dependencies, initialize git, and connect your repo to the remote repository hosted by Heroku.

**Note:** *if you already initialized your git before running `heroku create [app-name]`, then you don’t need to run `heroku git:remote -a [app-name].`*

**run `heroku open`** and your development app will open in your default browser. If you want a production build, I think you already know what to do. - > Create a production build of your ***`React`*** app. Create a proper `.gitignore` file so only the relevant files will be deployed.

**IMPORTANT:** If you already had a `.gitignore` file, make sure that this line isn't in it **`/build`** :)

May I also suggest reading this [blog](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration)! Have a good one!

Comment: Thanks You Bigga,

You are explaining me to deploy React as 1 app and Express as another application.

Where as in my case both ( expressJS [backend] and reactJS [frontend]) is a part of 1 application. 

So how can I bundle it as one application and deploy. 

regards

Comment: @SaifuddinSyed - ReactJS is a frontend framework that works in the browser. Express is a backend framework that works on top of NodeJS environment. 

Those two are very different things that work in a very different way. That's why we have terms like "backend" & "frontend". If you want you can deploy your React app with zero configs to e.g. Heroku (I suggest reading the blog attached to my answer), but if you want to have a NodeJS/ Express API that's works with your React app, well buddy, that's a whole different ball game. So, the short answer is NO.

Comment: @SaifuddinSyed May I suggest updating your question with a better explanation of what is exactly that you want, and a little bit of code wouldn't hurt. Cheers!

Comment: You can still deploy them on the same host. So even though you'll have an `Express` and a `React` app, they both can be on the same server (just different ports) and communicate with each other. Install `react router 4` and make sure the routes are correct, and it's a done deal. Just make your `Express` app serve `index.html` from your `React` app src or build folder. Like I showed you above in my answer. I hope you get the point. Have a good one.